# PHP Cookie User System If Statements

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to get php to choose which link should appear depending on if this person is logged into my site using cookies.I tried to code this my self but it isn't working.So How would I go about doing this the right way here is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['maxgee_me_user'])) {
$username = $_COOKIE['maxgee_me_user']; 
$password = $_COOKIE['maxgee_me_password']; 
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))   

    { 



//if the cookie has the wrong password, echo's login 

    if ($password != $_COOKIE['maxgee_me_password']) 

        {           ?> <a href="logout.php"><?php echo "Logout"; ?></a> &nbsp;&nbsp 
         <?php
    else {
    ?> <a href="loginpage.php"><?php echo "User Login";} ?></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: Storing a password in a cookie is very bad practice...

Comment: @Jasper I know I am planing on fixing that soon

Comment: What happens when you run the code, whats failing?

Comment: @SimonCarlson Right Now It is saying unexpected Else but before it was saying unexpected $end

Comment: The sample code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). To fix this hole, switch from the outdated mysql extension to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements), passing values as parameters to the statement rather than interpolating them directly into the string. If you need a PDO tutorial, try ["Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO"](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html). The site you save may just be your own.

Comment: Note that `or die(mysql_error())` should never appear in production code, as [`die`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) breaks HTML output and database error messages should never be revealed to non-admin users as it [discloses too much information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995351.aspx#securityerrormessages_topic2). A better approach would be to properly implement error handling (and use PDO instead of the outdated mysql extension, which is being deprecated).

Comment: You don't have to use a `while` loop when fetching results. If a query is supposed to return 0-or-1 results, using an `if` instead of a `while` will more clearly communicate intent.

Comment: Picking and applying a standard [indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) will make your code easier to read and make it easier to catch mistakes like the missing brace before the `else`. A decent code editor or IDE will support at least one indent style, taking care of much of the work for you.

Comment: Passwords... In cookies. It's like 1998 all over again. Don't do it.

Comment: @nickhar How else should I do it?

Comment: Use PHP's built-in `$_SESSION`. Write your variable(s) to `$_SESSION['username']` etc. You should never write or record the password anywhere other than in DB - only flag that they are authenticated and have permission to access content. Eg. `$_SESSION['authuser']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a lot of errors on your code.
First of all, you need to use both user name and password when checking if a valid user exist. Assuming you have the pwd saved as well in you table.

```
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password='$password'") or die(mysql_error());
```

And use mysql_num_rows($check)>0 to see if a valid user found.
Following is a complete code, but do note this is bad coding practise which you say you are working on it.

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['maxgee_me_user']))
{
    $username = $_COOKIE['maxgee_me_user']; 
    $password = $_COOKIE['maxgee_me_password']; 
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password='$password'") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($check)>0) 
    {

        ?>
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> &nbsp;&nbsp 
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <a href="loginpage.php"><?php echo "User Login"; ?></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?php
    }
}
else
{
    ?>
    <a href="loginpage.php"><?php echo "User Login"; ?></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: That code works except it isnt showing the Logout Link and only showing the User Login

Comment: Even after cookies are unset?

Comment: Check if the cookies has correct data and if they are in your user table as well. The code is only a guide for you, don't expect to work out of the box, you need to try different things, put echo statements etc to see where the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

You never read the password from the query.  You have this at the top:

```
$password = $_COOKIE['maxgee_me_password'];
```

And you're comparing it to itself farther down:

```
if ($password != $_COOKIE['maxgee_me_password'])
```

You can fix it by replacing the comparison with this:

```
if ($password != $info['password'])
```

You're also missing some curly braces.  You need to add one before the `else` and at the end of your code if that's not the end of the script.  With formatting and the above fixes:

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['maxgee_me_user'])) {
    $username = $_COOKIE['maxgee_me_user']; 
    $password = $_COOKIE['maxgee_me_password']; 
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());
    $info = mysql_fetch_array( $check );
    //if the cookie has the wrong password, echo's login 
    if ($password != $info['password']){ ?>
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <?php }else{ ?>
        <a href="loginpage.php">User Login</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I am still getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Comment: I just tried your code and I am getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Comment: @G-Nugget - I'm not sure why you are closing your PHP and then re-opening it so frequently. Instead just use one opening and one closing statement. Then in your logic that compares the passwords, use header("Location: /logout.php"); and header("Location: /loginpage.php"); It's cleaner and easier to debug that way.

Comment: @rsmith84 The links could be echoed, but I'm just going off of the original code and there is much more that could be improved in it.  The original code doesn't redirect, it just prints the links.

Comment: @G-Nugget; fair enough. I wasn't really telling YOU to use headers, merely a suggestion to the OP to help improve what he gave us.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_COOKIE["maxgee_user"])) {
        $username = $_COOKIE["maxgee_user"];
        $password = $_COOKIE["maxgee_password"];
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'");
        if(mysql_count_rows($q) > 0){
          print("<a href='/logoutpage.php'>Logout</a>");
        }else{
          print("<a href='/loginpage.php'>Login</a>");
        }
     }else{
          print("<a href='/loginpage.php'>Login</a>");
     }
 ?>
```

Quick and dirty. It's been years since i did any dev. in PHP, but i think i still remember the essentials. Remember to never trust input, included that saved in cookies, or you will be vulnerable to exploits. Good luck mate!

Comment: I am geting this error with your code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'on the second line

Comment: Also make sure you     mysql_real_escape_string() on ANY input that you are going to expose to a database or use in a query.

Comment: I am getting this error at the end line of code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end